# Browse files with vim in terminal

Tags: command-line, files, vim

Is there any way to open file with vim in the terminal without typing file name, but for example then I see in the directory my file, go with arrow keys or something like that?

I think I saw one of my old buddy choosing files with keys, but I am not very sure of that.

Answer (score 2):

In vim, if you type ":e ." (without the quotes), it will bring up the netrw file browser. You can select and open files from there. If you type "i" (without quotes), it will cycle through various views of the directory, including a simple "tree" file browser. Type ":help netrw" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend would have been using a [shell script](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=108553%29).

> My belief is that all file managers suck. There are no exceptions to this. So, for the past few months, I've been sourcing a file with a bunch of tricks I've invented / found through browsing the web to make using just bash as a file manager much more convenient.